# Eclipse RCP - Conflicting handlers for ltk rename command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, automated-refactoring

I am devloping an Eclipse RCP application in which I am writing my own refactoring code. I am overriding 
`org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource` command as follows:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
      defaultHandler="com.rename.command.CustomRenameHandler"
      id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource"
      name="Rename">
  </command>
</extension>
```

When I run the application, I get following error message

```
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource
```

Due to this, sometimes my handler is called and sometimes RenameResourceHandler is called.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override a command that already has an active or default handler.

For refactoring rename you should write a rename participant using the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point. Your participant will be called along with all the other participants that need to be run during a rename.

Comment: Hi Greg, in my project I have to show a different rename wizard than the default Eclipse one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will have to write your own command, menu items, and handler.